# How to change "Generate Method Stub" to throw NotImplementedException in VS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration

How can I change default [Generate Method Stub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a7hkh29.aspx) behavior in Visaul Studio to generate method with body

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

instead of

```
throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from: http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2005/12/08/501763.aspx

> Visual Studio 2005 supports targeting the 1.0 version of the compact framework.  In order to keep the size of the compact framework small, it does not include all of the same types that exist in the desktop framework.  One of the types that is not included is NotImplementedException.

You can change the generated code by editing the code snippet file:
**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodStub.snippet** and changing the Declarations section to the following:

```
        <Declarations>
            <Literal Editable="true">
                <ID>signature</ID>
                <Default>signature</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                <ID>Exception</ID>
                <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.NotImplementedException)</Function>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another reason: FxCop catches instances of anybody throwing 'Exception' and flags it, but throwing instances of 'NotImplementedException' is acceptable.

I actually like the default behavior, because it does have this differentiation. NotImplementedException is not a temporary exception to be thrown while you're working your way through your code. It implies "I mean it, I'm *really* not going to implement this thing". If you leave the codegen the way it is, it's easy for you to differentiate in the code the "I will come back to this later" bits from "I've decided not to do this" bits.

Comment: Well you can create your own NotYetImplementedException or WillNeverImplementThisMethodException or MissingCodeHereException or WillFixInNextVersionException :)