# How do I change '// TODO Auto-generated method stub' to something else in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I change **// TODO Auto-generated method stub** to something else in Eclipse, if at all possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Window - Preferences - Java - Code Style - Code Templates - Code - Method Body - `EDIT`

Answer (score 0):

see also [Auto-generate stub methods that throw in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092490/auto-generate-stub-methods-that-throw-in-eclipse) for the more specific point about changing it to throw new UnsupportedOperationException.